# Disadvantages to giving Spring Controller Session scope.

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like some feedback on giving Session scope to a Controller in Spring MVC.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/feedback/Controller")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION,
               proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Feedback { ...
```

It allows me to maintain state easily in the controller. I can inject several beans and then reuse the same beans throughout the entire session on multiple requests. Requests from different sessions do not conflict. The effect is like a Controller scope. Each controller has its own object in the session where all of its bean instances are stored.

It might be a bit of overkill, since most of the code in the controller does not maintain state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a overkill, but a very bad practice. It may work doesn't mean you should do it that way.

We can start by answering a few questions.

Why do you need maintain state inside the bean? What's the benefits of it over HttpSession?

If you are using Sessions cope bean, where do you think it's stored? Yes, it's in HttpSession!

Instead of only storing the state to HttpSession, you are storing the Bean.

Disadvantages? 
It introduces unnecessary overhead and it makes your session serialization and deserialization more complicated. Considering you are going to scale out to have more app servers...

I will always avoid session scope bean.

Comment: I have a bean that is used by two controllers. With session scope for the bean, both controllers share the data. I require that each controller has its own data for the bean.